# What is ? in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface Iterator<T> {
    next(value?: any): IteratorResult<T>;
    return?(value?: any): IteratorResult<T>;
    throw?(e?: any): IteratorResult<T>;
}
```

I am trying to learn Typescript and wanted to understand what is the meaning of **?** after **value** in next and also meaning of **?** after return and throw. Does IteratorResult represent the type of data returned?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but maybe `nullable` In .NET, `?` is the null coalescing operator.

Comment: It means value is optional

Comment: @Kokodoko So, that is the same as nullable.

Comment: @Kokodoko : So it means implementing the return and throw is also optional

Comment: If you implement this interface you have to include `next(value?:any)` but you can leave out `return` and `throw`.